# NodeJS MongoDB Connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, websocket, socket.io

I want to learn NodeJS and I decided to make a chat application for start. And I have a question. I will use Mongodb for database but I looked every website to login/Signup with MongoDB, I found nothing. Can you explain to me how can I connect MongoDB database to my project or any advice,resource website would be great.Thanks for your help.

P.S I am using visual studio to develop this application.

Comment: [http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to install mongoose from npm by this command:

> npm install --save mongoose

then,include following line of code:

> var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
>
> var db =
>   mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname');
>
> db.on('connected', function () {   logger.info('Mongoose connection open to master DB - '+ 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname'); });
>   module.exports = db;

Comment: Sorry, it could be bad question.I installed mongoose and I opened new script file and add this codes so, how can I access this database?

Answer (score -1):

This link is a course made by Mongodb University it teaches the basics of using mongodb with nodejs and express 
https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M101JS/about

You should subscribe to it and wait for the next session

You can also find the videos on Youtube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvcUO8DPWfs&list=PLRQuJcU2aZG-aMedJxa7p7ylYmOn5iMlS

A small example connection

```
to: localhost,
port : 27017,
database name : myData, collection name : myCollection, show every FirstName field in the collection.
```

```js
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    assert = require('assert');

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myData', function(err, db) {

    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB.");

 var query = {}
   
 var projectionFields = {"FirstName":1,"_id":0}
      db.collection('myCollection').find(query, projectionFields)
            .toArray(function(err, docs) {
              docs.forEach(function(item, index){
      console.log(item);
              }
   })
});
```

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).